# Django issue with angular

Tags: django

I am trying to deploy my application using below tech stack:

- Angular - Frontend
- Django - Backend

When I am trying to access over https my app the backend is giving following error

```
Not Found: /
[05/Jul/2021 00:57:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2356
[05/Jul/2021 02:42:50] code 400, message Bad request version ('À\x14À')
[05/Jul/2021 02:42:50] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the development server to host the application, this is not suggested and does not work with `https` only `http`.

Use a production grade server like:

1. Apache
2. Nginx
3. Others

For more information visit the [django-depolyment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/) docs

You will also need to generate and sign a https certificate, for that I would suggest using [Lets Encrpty](https://letsencrypt.org/)